# Typescript - Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: typescript

I can't seem to figure it out how to solve it. It is throwing the following error: `Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'`.

This is my code. Any idea or any tips are much appreciated.

---

```
interface User {
    name: string
    age: number
}

const user: User = {
    name: "someone",
    age: 20
}

const getValue = (key: keyof User) => {
    return user[key]
}

const setValue = (key: keyof User, value: string | number) => {

    let _user: User = Object.assign({}, user);
    return _user[key] = value;  <---- error is thrown here
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The way in which you have declared your types in the `setValue` function results in Typescript correctly determining that there are no possible values of type `_user[key]`.

Let's explore this in more detail.

### The Problem

Your `User` interface contains two properties, one of type `string` and one of type `number`.

The `key` parameter of your `setValue` function is of type `keyof User`.

All good so far...

However, at 'compile-time' Typescript has no way to determine *which* key  is being provided for lookup, and therefore cannot determine which specific type `_user[key]` is.

What Typescript *does* know at compile-time, is that is either of type `string` or `number`. Therefore it infers the *intersection* type `string & number`.

Which set of types are **both** strings **and** numbers?

Correct - there are no such types; Typescript therefore correctly infers that the type of `_user[key]` is the empty set of types - known as the `never` type.

### Simple Demos

---

Firstly, open your favorite IDE with Typescript hinting, and define a variable with an intersection type:

```
let a : string & number;
```

Descriptively, this is saying that the the type of `a` is the set of all possible types that are both `string` and `number`.

Typescript correctly infers that there are, in fact, no such types, and `a` is therefore of type `never`.

[image: VS Code screenshot]

---

Conversely, imagine that your `User` interface instead had both properties of type `string`.

```
interface User {
    name: string
    age: string
}
```

In this case, your code would work fine, if you pass in and use only strings.

This is equivalent to saying that the type of `_user[key]` is the intersection type `string & string` - which of course is simply `string`;

[image: VS Code screenshot 2]

---

### The Solution

In order to have correct type inference in your `setValue` function, you need to provide a generic type, that you can make use of for both the `key` and `value` parameters of your `setValue` function:

```
const setValue = <K extends keyof User>(key: K, value: User[K]) => {
  const _user: User = Object.assign({}, user); // Consider also the ES6 spread operator here
  _user[key] = value;
  return _user;
};
```

Or, if you want an entirely generic `setValue` function, independent of a specific type or object, your function signature could be as follows

```
const setValueOnObj = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K, value: T[K]) => [...]
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
const setValue = <K extends keyof User>(key: K, value: User[K]) => {
  let _user: User = Object.assign({}, user);
  return _user[key] = value;
}
```

Then you can get perfect type checking

```
setValue('name', 18); // ❌
setValue('name', 'yes'); // ✅
setValue('age', '18'); // ❌
setValue('age', 18); // ✅
setValue('otherKey', 'something'); // ❌
```

Answer (score 3):

A little bit improved solution for one provided by Simon L, with less generic parameters:

```
const setValue = <T>(obj: T, key: keyof T, value: T[keyof T]) => { obj[key] = value }
```

Comment: I like the solution since it worx ;-) The other solutions its highly unclear what `user` is (especially in the example) and how to pick a specific key which needs to be assigned